# Access Denied When Retrieving Static Image From S3 Bucket

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3

I am trying to store and display pictures I have uploaded through React.
Storing them works fine.  I can view them when I manually open my S3 bucket.
When I try to display them, I get a 403 error and if I click on the link returned to me I am shown an xml file like this:

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>9E7DA968420809CA</RequestId>
<HostId>
vHBWGUStVMowVcphdjBXqetPIPGeV/xSd2aD70GSKqja2QhQgLirz9hcT5zj6bWogI4u4Z/6918=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

Here is my React code:

```
import React , {Component} from 'react';
act-s3';
import S3FileUpload from 'react-s3';
import { uploadFile } from 'react-s3';

const config = {
    bucketName: 'testmypictures', // name of the bucket
    dirName: 'photos', /* optional */
    region: 'us-east-1',
    accessKeyId: 'xxxxxx',
    secretAccessKey: 'xxxxxxx',
}

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state ={
      url: u,
    }
    this.upload = this.upload.bind(this);
  }

  upload(e) {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    S3FileUpload.uploadFile(file, config)
      .then(data => this.setState({url: data.location}))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  render() {
    return ( <div>
      Upload AWS S3
      <input 
        type="file"
        onChange={this.upload}
      />
      <img src={this.state.url} />
    </div>);
  }
}

export default App;
```

And attached is the picture of the error.
Thanks.

Comment: Does your bucket have a **Bucket Policy** that makes it public?

Answer (score 0):

The error message says `Access Denied`. This either indicates that the object does not exist or the the requester does not have permission to access the object.

You are not putting any authentication in the `<img>` tag, which means the object needs to be publicly accessible to be accessed. (That is, S3 doesn't know who you are, so it is not providing the object. If an object or bucket is publicly accessible, then the object *can* be accessed.)

There are two ways to do this:

- You can make the whole `testmypictures` bucket (or part of it) public by using a **Bucket Policy**, or
- You can mark the individual objects as public while uploading them by specifying an **Access Control List** (ACL)